# How to use attribute type "Set" in lightning

Tags: aura-attribute

Unable to create "set" from aura controller and use it in lightning.Its not working properly.

**Component:**

```
<aura:attribute name = "setObj" type = "List" default="[]"/> 
<aura:iteration items="{!v.setObj}" var="item"> {!item} </aura:iteration>
```

**controller.js**

```
var setItems=new Set(); 
setItems.add("item1"); 
setItems.add("item2"); 
setItems.add("item1"); 
setItems.add("item4"); 
component.set("v.setObj",setItems);
```

Output is always :  [object Set]

Comment: Hello Maneesh, Welcome to SFSE. Can you please explain little bit more, what is your requirement and what you have done to achieve this?

Comment: I want to iterate set object but it not working properly.

Aura Component
<aura:attribute name = "setObj" type = "List" default="[]"/>
   <aura:iteration items="{!v.setObj}" var="item">
         {!item}
</aura:iteration>

Controller
var setItems=new Set();
        setItems.add("item1");
        setItems.add("item2");
        setItems.add("item1");
        setItems.add("item4");
        component.set("v.setObj",setItems);

Output
[object Set]
@DhanikLalSahni

Comment: Please add this code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set is Keyed collection](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-set-vs-array-what-and-when-efc055655e1a) and it is saved as object. So you will not get array from it. You have to convert into array to use iteration.

Your value will be saved like {item1,item2, item4} instead of [item1,item2,item4]. So before setting values convert into array.

**component**

```
  <aura:attribute name="setObj" type="string[]" />
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.setObj}" var="items"> 
    {!items}
  </aura:iteration>
```

**controller.js**

```
 var setItems = new Set();
    setItems.add("item1");
    setItems.add("item2");
    setItems.add("item1");
    setItems.add("item4");
    component.set("v.setObj", Array.from(setItems));
```